# Is it necessary to develop an iPhone Native App with session token controlling at server-side?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, security, token

**Hello**, everybody.

I am developing an iPhone native app(including webview in it) which could communicate with my server-side webservice.
The system has user management module which user could login/out, chanage theirs own information.

Come with usual cases such as a web site, there must be token or something else for security consideration.
Then what about iPhone native app? Because my webservice could only access from the app so that I think it is secure enough, is it also necessary to implement at the session token way?

Thanks, Best regards.

Answer (score 2):

How are you going to do identification/authentication without token?

I believe when you enter User/Password the this authentication pair + device_id is sent (using SSL) to the server, then in case of successful authentication server returns session token (session could be unlimited by time, it is up to you) for this device_id. Login and token are saved somewhere in your program (e.g. in defaults key/value storage). Password should be never saved anywhere in program.

When user launches your app, app sends Login, token and device_id to the server, server checks and say OK+session_key or NOK. In case of NOK you delete login and token from your app's storage and display login form again. If response was OK - you send HTTP requests + session key and server replies you. Something like that...

PS: I believe it should be like that, however I don't have much experience in Web.

Comment: HI, @OgreSwamp, thanks for your reply. In fact, I am just using uname and pwd to identification/authentication each user. I could get the session token at server-side but I didn't user it as just thinking it is could only be accessed from my app. By the way, I am considering that before its release, I would change it to SSL connection. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Are you asking for login/password each time?
2) How you're validating that it is same user as the one who entered password?
3) What will stop me to send HTTP request to your app from my browser?

Fact that you provide access to the web service only from app doesn't make **any protection** against attack.

Comment: 1)A:Once user logout, he/she has to login again to use the app; 2)A:I don't validate the same user as he/she only know the pwd belonged to him/herself. 3)A:I have done something at server-side that it could only be accessed from my app but not any browser including the built-in safari in iPhone. Thanks.